# How to checkout a resource from code in UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm

I want to upload and excel file in ALM via UFT code. The problem is that we have a version control activated and then I need checkout the resource before upload the file. I see in the documentation the method CheckOut but... doesn't work. In the internet I found this :

```
Set fVersionControl = oNewResource.VC
fVersionControl.CheckOut -1, "comment", False
```

But doesn't work...

My code is this:

```
For iNowResourceNum = 1 To resourceCount
    nowResource = oCurrentResources.Item(iNowResourceNum).Name
    If UCase(nowResource) = UCase(QcResourceName) Then
        Set oNewResource = oCurrentResources.Item(iNowResourceNum)
        resourceFound = "True"
    End If
Next

If resourceFound="True" Then
    Set fVersionControl = oNewResource.VC
    fVersionControl.CheckOut -1, "comment", False
    oNewResource.FileName=fileName
    oNewResource.ResourceType="Data table"
    oNewResource.Post
    oNewResource.UploadResource pathToSave, True
    fVersionControl.CheckIn "",""
    Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "Resource found", "Resource Found"
else
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Resource doesnt found", "Resource doesnt found"
End If

oNewResource = null
nowResource = null
oCurrentResources = null
QCResourceManager = null
```

How can I do checkout of a resource?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

1-Replace "fVersionControl.CheckOut -1, "comment", False" by

> Set CheckoutEntity = fVersionControl
>
> fVersionControl.CheckOut comment

2- Replace "fVersionControl.CheckIn "",""  "  by

> Set CheckinEntity = fVersionControl
>
> fVersionControl.Checkin comment

This works for me. Hope it'll be helpfull